# Creating Custom Object in Salesforce Lightning using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to practice using Selenium by doing a simple operation of creating a custom object in Salesforce Lightning. My code works fine in Classic, but once I switch over to Lightning, for some reason it only works up to a certain point.

What works:

```
driver.get("http://login.salesforce.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='username']")).sendKeys("<USERNAME>");      
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys("<PASSWORD>");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='button r4 wide primary']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"oneHeader\"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul[2]/li[3]/div")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"oneHeader\"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul[2]/li[3]/div/div[2]")).click();
```

So I am able to login and access the Object Create page just fine. The issue is with the next bit of code, which should be the easiest:

````
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='MasterLabel']")).sendKeys("Address");      
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='MasterLabel']")).sendKeys("Addresses");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value=' Save ']")).click();```
````

I keep getting the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='MasterLabel']"}
```

Things I have tried:

1. Searching for the input boxes via name and id instead of xpath. Same results
2. Tried implementing an explicit wait. Doesn't seem to make a difference
3. Tried doing a driver.switchTo().frame() method, but Webdriver can't seem to detect an iFrame on the 
   page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Go to the page, Press F12, go to elements, press ctrl+F and paste the xpath. It will tell whether your xpath is valid or not

Comment: Yes, I have done that, and the xpath is valid.

Comment: will your input box appear only while hovering?

Comment: No, it's there when the page loads.

Comment: Try with a css selector

Comment: I'm not familiar with using ccs selector, but doing some research, I tried this: `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id=MasterLabel]")).sendKeys("Address");` Is this the correct syntax? In either case, I tried this and it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you post the sample DOM of that element. So, that it can be little helpful to identify the correctness of your `xpath`.